# How to restrict Input box with 2 decimal places in Angular 2/4/5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I had a scenario that I should restrict a input box with 2 decimal places in Angular 2/4/5. Should I write a directive for this?

example: 12.25, 14524.21, 12547896324.01

We should not allow user to enter extra keystroke after completion of two decimal values

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. Please try to write some code before asking. Visit this website to learn more: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this regex

```
/^\d*(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?$/
```

Comment: Your solution is work only if someone use Reactive forms, But what if someone use  [(ngModel)]. For that you can create directives it work for both.

Answer (score 2):

- Add below code in your HTML file 
  `<label>Enter value</label> <br/> 
  <input type="text" name="test" placeholder="00.00" [(ngModel)]="textValue" appIsDecimal>`
- Declare textValue variable in ts file.
- Then create Directive by below command `ng g d IsDecimalDirective`
- Add that Directive **declarations** part of your module.
- In the IsDecimalDirective file write below code

  ```
  import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, forwardRef, Attribute, AfterContentInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
  import { NG_VALIDATORS, AbstractControl, ValidatorFn, Validator, FormControl, NgModel } from '@angular/forms';

  @Directive({
      selector: '[IsDecimal]'
  })
  export class IsDecimalDirective {

    private regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/^\d*\.?\d{0,2}$/g);
    private specialKeys: Array<string> = ['Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home', '-', 'ArrowLeft', 'ArrowRight', 'Del', 'Delete'];

    constructor(
      private el: ElementRef
    ) { }

    @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
    onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {

    // Allow Backspace, tab, end, and home keys
    if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(event.key) !== -1) {
       return;
    }

    let current: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
    const position = this.el.nativeElement.selectionStart;
    const next: string = [current.slice(0, position), event.key == 'Decimal' ? '.' : event.key, current.slice(position)].join('');

        if (next && !String(next).match(this.regex)) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
        }
    }
  ```
- Here is a link  for [StackBits demo](https://angular-decimal-validation-directive.stackblitz.io)

Comment: please provide the answer link

Comment: I have already attached link in my answer above @abhinavxeon
https://angular-decimal-validation-directive.stackblitz.io/

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use a Validator for that :

```
this.myReactiveForm = this._formBuilder.group({
  myNumber: ['', [Validators.pattern(/^\d*(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?$/)]]
});
```